# Why the '?' operator in Perl's regex didn't work here?

Tags: regex, perl

Given the following input:

```
micro RNA 155
micro-RNA-155
```

I want to normalize them such that both of them returns this:

```
miR-155
```

But why this regex doesn't work

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
  my $mirn = $ARGV[0];
  $mirn =~ s/micro-?RNA-?(\d+)/miR-$1/gi;

  print "$mirn\n";
```

Comment: Your regexp says that `-` is optional, it doesn't say that space is allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't account for the spaces.

```
s/micro[\- ]RNA[\- ](\d)/miR-$1/gi;
```

or

```
s/micro[\- ]RNA[\- ](?=\d)/miR-/gi;
```

Comment: Why the backslashes before the dashes?  When the dash is the first character in a character class (or the second in a negated character class) it stands for itself, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, It's not required, but I wanted to signal to the OP that they can have special meaning in character classes.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
s/micro[- ]RNA[- ](\d+)/miR-$1/gi;
```

This says that the words can be separated either by hyphen or space. Your regexp says that they can be separated by hyphen or must be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

The Space may be come before & after hyphen..

```
s/micro\s*-?\s*Rna\s*-?\s*(\d+)/miR-$1/igs
```

Comment: This will match eg. `microRna123`. Not sure that is wanted.